# Why is it possible to access 'module.exports' as just 'exports' but not so with 'module.id'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

This is my code in a file named `foo.js`.

```
console.log('module.exports:', module.exports)
console.log('module.id:', module.id)
console.log('exports:', exports)
console.log('id:', id)
```

This is the output I get.

```
$ node foo.js
module.exports: {}
module.id: .
exports: {}
/home/lone/foo.js:4
console.log('id:', id)
                   ^

ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lone/foo.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Here is what I am unable to understand. Both `exports` and `id` are
attributes of the `module` object. But I am able to access `exports`
without the `module.` qualifier but I unable to do so for the `id`
attribute.

Why is it so? What are the concepts at play here that makes it possible
to access `module.exports` as just `exports` but not so with
`module.id`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how NodeJS behaves. Every code that you write is eventually wrapped into a self-calling function with some specific arguments.

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // your code
})()
```

That is why even `module` and `require` are available to you directly.

> Why is it so? What are the concepts at play here that makes it possible to access module.exports as just exports but not so with module.id?

It's not that you can access properties of the module, but `exports` has been provided explicitly for the ease of access.

**Important Note:** `exports` and `module.exports` have the same reference, that means any change to either one will reflect on other.

**NodeJS Docs**: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper

**More Reference**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WUFqLwfUwM&list=PLKT6oJQ4t2f-sL50I51a64jBoCknFFJy9

Comment: @Lone Learner If this answered your question, please consider accepting it as an answer.